# Visualize graphs in java

Tags: java, graphviz, graphstream

I'm currently working on a university project to implement simple graph algorithms in java 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) 
and I'm struggling to find a simple solution to export my created graphs into a image file (i.e. .png)

I already looked at tools like GraphViz and GraphStream, but they seem to focus more on visualizing their own code to create graphs.

Has anybody knowledge of a simple library or maybe even external tool which can interpret my generated output in a image file? If possible something lightweight and easy to implement.

[My code] ---> [Output] ---> [What I'm in search of] ---> [Image File]

Comment: What does your output language look like?

Comment: There is no output in the moment. My line of thought was to gather all 'components' first and getting to work as my second step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate output in the Graphviz Dot language, you can visualize it with `dotty` and export to PNG or other image formats with the `dot` program. The Dot language is very simple, for example here's a directed graph with 3 nodes making a cycle, and a self-edge in the third node.

```
digraph {
A -> B
B -> C
C -> A
C -> C
}
```

This is how it's rendered in dotty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are loosely stated, but here are some answers:

- If you want 'in search of' to place both nodes & edges, then the answer above works
- If you want to place the nodes yourself, graphviz supports this - search the FAQ for "already have all the coordinates for the nodes".  **dot -Tdot yourinputfile** will give an example of the output you need to create.  You can skip the **pos** on the edges.
- If you want to place both nodes and edges, see above but include the **pos** on the edges and use **neato -n2**  (edges are always splines, but straight edges are easy to calculate)

  - Doesn't java have graphice routines you could use?
- If you want to position nodes and edges but don't like the graphviz solution, try dpic (https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/dpic/)  It is slightly lower-level and gives you more control

Good luck